# Python - scapy packet size difference

Tags: python, size, packet, scapy, packet-sniffers

I'm sending and recieving a packet with the module scapy.

```
a = sr(IP(src="192.168.1.100",dst="8.8.4.4")/UDP(sport=RandShort(),dport=53)/DNS(rd=1,qd=DNSQR(qname="google.com",qtype="ALL",qclass="IN"),ar=DNSRROPT(rclass=3000)),timeout=1)
```

If I display the packet size of of the command and response:

```
#command size
print len(a[0][0][0])
>67

#response size
print len(a[0][0][1])
>496
```

But if I capture the packets with Wireshark, it shows me a packet length:

```
command:  83 bytes
response: 512 bytes
```

So we know in Wireshark we have an additional size of 16 bytes for command and response..

```
83-67   =16
512-496 =16
```

And I want to know (just for educational proposes) what are the additional 16 bytes captured by Wireshark? Somebody have a deep 'knowhow' in networking and can tell me what happens?

EDIT:

Output of `a[0].summary()`:

```
IP / UDP / DNS Qry "google.com"  ==> IP / UDP / DNS Ans "74.125.68.102"
```

Output of `a[0][0][0].show()`:

```
###[ IP ]###
  version   = 4
  ihl       = None
  tos       = 0x0
  len       = **67**
  id        = 1
  flags     = 
  frag      = 0
  ttl       = 64
  proto     = udp
  chksum    = None
  src       = 192.168.1.100
  dst       = 8.8.4.4
  \options   \
###[ UDP ]###
     sport     = 41454
     dport     = domain
     len       = None
     chksum    = None
###[ DNS ]###
        id        = 0
        qr        = 0
        opcode    = QUERY
        aa        = 0
        tc        = 0
        rd        = 1
        ra        = 0
        z         = 0
        ad        = 0
        cd        = 0
        rcode     = ok
        qdcount   = 1
        ancount   = 0
        nscount   = 0
        arcount   = 1
        \qd        \
         |###[ DNS Question Record ]###
         |  qname     = 'google.com'
         |  qtype     = ALL
         |  qclass    = IN
        an        = None
        ns        = None
        \ar        \
         |###[ DNS OPT Resource Record ]###
         |  rrname    = '.'
         |  type      = OPT
         |  rclass    = 3000
         |  extrcode  = 0
         |  version   = 0
         |  z         = D0
         |  rdlen     = None
         |  \rdata     \
```

Output of `a[0].show()`:

```
###[ IP ]###
  version   = 4L
  ihl       = 5L
  tos       = 0x0
  len       = **496**
  id        = 41777
  flags     = 
  frag      = 0L
  ttl       = 56
  proto     = udp
  chksum    = 0xfb3
  src       = 8.8.4.4
  dst       = 192.168.1.100
  \options   \
###[ UDP ]###
     sport     = domain
     dport     = 41454
     len       = 476
     chksum    = 0x2fef
###[ DNS ]###
        id        = 0
        qr        = 1L
        opcode    = QUERY
        aa        = 0L
        tc        = 0L
        rd        = 1L
        ra        = 1L
        z         = 0L
        ad        = 0L
        cd        = 0L
        rcode     = ok
        qdcount   = 1
        ancount   = 19
        nscount   = 0
        arcount   = 1
        \qd        \
         |###[ DNS Question Record ]###
         |  qname     = 'google.com.'
         |  qtype     = ALL
         |  qclass    = IN
        \an        \
         |###[ DNS Resource Record ]###
         |  rrname    = 'google.com.'
         |  type      = A
         |  rclass    = IN
         |  ttl       = 299
         |  rdlen     = 4
         |  rdata     = '74.125.68.102'
         |###[ DNS Resource Record ]###
         |  rrname    = 'google.com.'
         |  type      = A
         |  rclass    = IN
         |  ttl       = 299
         |  rdlen     = 4
         |  rdata     = '74.125.68.113'
         |###[ DNS Resource Record ]###
         |  rrname    = 'google.com.'
         |  type      = A
         |  rclass    = IN
         |  ttl       = 299
         |  rdlen     = 4
         |  rdata     = '74.125.68.139'
         |###[ DNS Resource Record ]###
         |  rrname    = 'google.com.'
         |  type      = A
         |  rclass    = IN
         |  ttl       = 299
         |  rdlen     = 4
         |  rdata     = '74.125.68.100'
         |###[ DNS Resource Record ]###
         |  rrname    = 'google.com.'
         |  type      = A
         |  rclass    = IN
         |  ttl       = 299
         |  rdlen     = 4
         |  rdata     = '74.125.68.138'
         |###[ DNS Resource Record ]###
         |  rrname    = 'google.com.'
         |  type      = A
         |  rclass    = IN
         |  ttl       = 299
         |  rdlen     = 4
         |  rdata     = '74.125.68.101'
         |###[ DNS Resource Record ]###
         |  rrname    = 'google.com.'
         |  type      = AAAA
         |  rclass    = IN
         |  ttl       = 299
         |  rdlen     = 16
         |  rdata     = '2404:6800:4003:c02::65'
         |###[ DNS Resource Record ]###
         |  rrname    = 'google.com.'
         |  type      = NS
         |  rclass    = IN
         |  ttl       = 21599
         |  rdlen     = 16
         |  rdata     = 'ns2.google.com.'
         |###[ DNS Resource Record ]###
         |  rrname    = 'google.com.'
         |  type      = MX
         |  rclass    = IN
         |  ttl       = 599
         |  rdlen     = 17
         |  rdata     = '\x00\x14\x04alt1\x05aspmx\x01l\xc0\x0c'
         |###[ DNS Resource Record ]###
         |  rrname    = 'google.com.'
         |  type      = SOA
         |  rclass    = IN
         |  ttl       = 59
         |  rdlen     = 34
         |  rdata     = '\xc0\xa4\tdns-admin\xc0\x0c\x07\xbe\xf2\xb0\x00\x00\x03\x84\x00\x00\x03\x84\x00\x00\x07\x08\x00\x00\x00<'
         |###[ DNS Resource Record ]###
         |  rrname    = 'google.com.'
         |  type      = MX
         |  rclass    = IN
         |  ttl       = 599
         |  rdlen     = 9
         |  rdata     = '\x00(\x04alt3\xc0\xbd'
         |###[ DNS Resource Record ]###
         |  rrname    = 'google.com.'
         |  type      = MX
         |  rclass    = IN
         |  ttl       = 599
         |  rdlen     = 4
         |  rdata     = '\x00\n\xc0\xbd'
         |###[ DNS Resource Record ]###
         |  rrname    = 'google.com.'
         |  type      = 257
         |  rclass    = IN
         |  ttl       = 21599
         |  rdlen     = 19
         |  rdata     = '\x00\x05issuesymantec.com'
         |###[ DNS Resource Record ]###
         |  rrname    = 'google.com.'
         |  type      = NS
         |  rclass    = IN
         |  ttl       = 21599
         |  rdlen     = 16
         |  rdata     = 'ns3.google.com.'
         |###[ DNS Resource Record ]###
         |  rrname    = 'google.com.'
         |  type      = MX
         |  rclass    = IN
         |  ttl       = 599
         |  rdlen     = 9
         |  rdata     = '\x00\x1e\x04alt2\xc0\xbd'
         |###[ DNS Resource Record ]###
         |  rrname    = 'google.com.'
         |  type      = NS
         |  rclass    = IN
         |  ttl       = 21599
         |  rdlen     = 16
         |  rdata     = 'ns1.google.com.'
         |###[ DNS Resource Record ]###
         |  rrname    = 'google.com.'
         |  type      = MX
         |  rclass    = IN
         |  ttl       = 599
         |  rdlen     = 9
         |  rdata     = '\x002\x04alt4\xc0\xbd'
         |###[ DNS Resource Record ]###
         |  rrname    = 'google.com.'
         |  type      = TXT
         |  rclass    = IN
         |  ttl       = 3599
         |  rdlen     = 36
         |  rdata     = 'v=spf1 include:_spf.google.com ~all'
         |###[ DNS Resource Record ]###
         |  rrname    = 'google.com.'
         |  type      = NS
         |  rclass    = IN
         |  ttl       = 21599
         |  rdlen     = 16
         |  rdata     = 'ns4.google.com.'
        ns        = None
        \ar        \
         |###[ DNS OPT Resource Record ]###
         |  rrname    = '.'
         |  type      = OPT
         |  rclass    = 512
         |  extrcode  = 0
         |  version   = 0
         |  z         = D0
         |  rdlen     = 0
         |  \rdata     \
```

Comment: You should post the output of `a[0].summary()` to let people understand what is going on here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are using the `.len` attribute of the packet, which, in your case, happen to be the value of the `len` field of the `IP` layer. It does not contain the `Ether` layer (14 bytes).

You should use `len()` (as you do in your example) to get the packet length. Also, you should specify the layer 2 (and hence, use `srp()` instead of `sr()`):

```
a = srp(Ether() / IP(src="192.168.1.100",dst="8.8.4.4") /
        UDP(sport=RandShort(),dport=53) /
        DNS(rd=1,qd=DNSQR(qname="google.com",qtype="ALL",qclass="IN"),
            ar=DNSRROPT(rclass=3000)),
        timeout=1)

print len(a[0][0][0]), len(a[0][0][1])
```

Comment: No, I don't think so. You can use `tshark -T pdml` to understand exactly what Wireshark sees.